# No ttyACM0 nor ttyUSB0

Tags: serial, usb, linux

I checked several related posts but couldn't solve my problem.

I have Antergos Linux :

```
# uname -a
Linux biutitude 4.14.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 3 07:02:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The board is a Seeeduino Lorawan.

The problem is that the menu to select the port is greyed, and when I check in /dev I don't see any new tty when I plug the card. However the card blinks.

I tried :
- adding myself to lock + tty + uucp (and restarted my session)
- created a dialout group because I didn't have one, added myself to it
- loading cdc_acm module but got the following error :

```
# modprobe cdc_acm
modprobe: FATAL: Module cdc_acm not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.11-1-ARCH
```

Thus I tried :

```
[root@biutitude biu]# depmod -ae
depmod: WARNING: -e needs -E or -F
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.14.11-1-ARCH: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
[root@biutitude biu]# depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.14.11-1-ARCH: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

I'm clearly out of ideas. The weirdest is that a few months ago, I was able to use a RFduino card without any trouble.

Comment: Run `watch lsusb`, then plug in the board. Does it show a new entry in the list? If so, what does it say?

Comment: `dmesg -w` is your friend. Run that, plug in the board, and look what it tells you.

Answer (score 2):

My solution - install linux-modules-extra kernel module on ubuntu 20.04. Solved my problem which was identical.

Get OS details:

```
uname -a
Linux seeeduino-node 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Install the sudo apt install linux-modules-extra:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-<kernel-version>
```

Example:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-91-generic
```

You need to reboot the machine afterwards it should work.